# Variable interval x-axis in Librecalc

Tags: libreoffice

For plot between two variables, particularly when the x-data are not equally spaced, the plot looks like this.

[image: here]

As you can observe that the x-axis data are not equally spaced actually. But the plot shows with uniform spacing. Can someone provide a solution for this?

Comment: It looks like you are using the wrong chart type for your needs - 'Line' instead of 'XY (scatter)'

Comment: Actually 'XY (Scatter)' instead of 'Line'. Post it as answer. Thanks!